# Explicit L-factor for supercuspidals

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, l-functions, functoriality

I am interested in **L-functions for the quasi-split unitary group $U$ in three variables**, following the construction by zeta integrals of Gelbart-Piatetski-Shapiro. My aim is to understand the consistency of this definition with the corresponding L-functions in $GL_3(E)$ where $E$ is the quadratic extension with which $U$ is defined.

In the unramified principal series case, say $\pi$, Gelbart and Piatetski-Shapiro show that the L-factor attached to $\pi$ by their construction in the unitary group match the L-factor attached to the base change of $\pi$ in $GL_3$ (I willingly do not write it in details to avoid unnecessary notations, but I will if necessary).

Let us look at the **supercuspidal case**. In [this paper](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1468-5.pdf) of Ishikawa, the L-factors are computed for any kind of representation of $U$. For instance for supercuspidals, it is announced (Prop 3) to be
$$L(s, \pi) = L_E(s, 1)$$

However, Rogawski tells us that the base chance of a supercuspidal representations remains supercuspidal in $GL_3(E)$, and hence the corresponding $L$-function in $GL_3$ should be
$$L(s, BC(\pi)) = 1$$

I wonder if those really differ or if there indeed a factor $L_E(s, 1)$ in the $GL$ case?

Comment: I think you just need to do the calculations to check if Ishikawa is right or not.  Integral constructions of $L$-functions do not always give you the "correct" $L$-factors at bad places.

Comment: @Kimball However this is my point: there is not any computation nor reference at all in Ishikawa for those computations and I do not understand how to compute them for supercuspidals (that are much less explicit than the unramified case)... Do you have any clue?

Comment: I haven't thought about it, but Ishikawa describes a method for doing the calculations, and says it follows Takloo-Bighash.  So perhaps you should try going through TB's approach for supercuspidals of GSp(4) first.  BTW, in case you're interested he seems to write up some more details for the Steinberg case in a note [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/1398.html).